# Error 3191 trying to add linked tables with Tabledefs

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i'm trying to add linked tables from MYSQL DB to Access and when i try do to that i get the error "Cannot define field more than once. (Error 3191)". That's because on my SQL DB i have two schemas "dev" and "test" with the same exact tables.

```
Public Sub start()
Const dbAttachedODBC = 536870912
Const dbAttachSavePWD = 131072
Const AppEnum As String = "TEST"
Dim tDefs As TableDefs
Set tDefs = Application.CurrentDb.TableDefs
Dim tDef As TableDef

Dim stLocalTableName As String
Dim stRemoteTableName As String
Dim stConnect As String
Dim stDatabase As String
Dim AttributeLong As Long
If AppEnum = "TEST" Then
    stDatabase = "test"
Else
    stDatabase = "dev"
End If

stLocalTableName = "venditore"
stRemoteTableName = "venditore"
stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver;SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=root;PWD=root;NO_I_S=1;FULL_COLUMN_NAMES=1;NO_BIGINT=1;BIG_PACKETS=1;FOUND_ROWS=1;"
AttributeLong = dbAttachSavePWD
Set tDef = Application.CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName)

With tDef
    '.Name = stLocalTableName
    .Connect = stConnect
    .SourceTableName = stRemoteTableName
    .attributes = AttributeLong
End With

tDefs.Append tDef
```

In the "stconnect" string i tried "NO_I_S=1" option and yesterday was working. Today he just doesn't.
I also explicit the schema where i want to get tables, so i just don't get it why it can't go there and grab the right ones.
Thanks in advance.

update----

I create another database called "aldb". "Aldb" and "dev" are working super fine, just "test" is the problem, but i don't understand why.

Comment: *That's because on my SQL DB i have two schemas "dev" and "test" with the same exact tables.* Try to specify complete table name which includes schema (database) name.

Comment: @Akina i can't do it or i don't know where i can, if i specify that in "stRemoteTableName" i got another error